# Disallow if user eneter All special characters in textbox validation c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, special-characters

I am working on validation, i have to validate a textbox, in which i need to disallow the special characters to enter. i mean if user fill only special characters in the textbox then we need to disallow him, if he is using **test-test** or **test_test** or **(999)-998-1111** then we need to allow user to enter the data.

i have used the below regular expression, but this is disallowing all, even i enter a single Special Character. it shows me error.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="ReqValContactPerson_SpecialChars" runat="server" CssClass="changecolor" 
                    ControlToValidate="txtFirstName" Display="Dynamic" 
                    ErrorMessage="Please enter valid first name" SetFocusOnError="True" 
                    ValidationExpression="[\%\/\\\&\?\,\'\;\:\!\-]+" 
                    ></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below regex won't allow only the mentioned special characters to be present on that textbox.

```
ValidationExpression="^(?![\%\/\\\&\?\,\'\;\:\!\-]+$).+"
```

OR

To disallow only digits and / or non-word characters.

```
 ValidationExpression="^(?![\d\W]+$).+"
```

`\W` matches any non-word character. `\d+` matches one or more digits.

That is, this won't allow `%&'` but allows this `f%G'`. Change `.+` to `.*` only if you want to allow blank lines also.

Comment: when i add %&^%& or !@#$%^&*()  its not showing me error, means its accepting this, but i don't want that....

Comment: add the extra special characters to the above character class. that is, `@`, `^`, etc..but don't put `^` at the first inside the charcter class. See my update..

Comment: Nice, Exactly what I needed right now! once again, Thanks:)

Comment: try now... I think you don't want to allow only numeric and special chars.

Comment: add `_` to character class if you don't want to allow `______`

Comment: @AvinashRaj : i commented when your regex was `^(?!\W+$).+` before the final edit

Answer (score 1):

You can test it with LINQ:

```
string str = "test-test";
bool allow = str.Any(c => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c));  //true

string str2 = "____!&&**^%$##@";      
bool allow2 = str2.Any(c => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)); // false

string str3 = "(999)-998-1111";
bool allow3 = str3.Any(c => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)); // true
```